# how to get character value?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a piece of code like this...

```
char c = 'a';
```

When I ask for `Character.getNumericValue(c)`, it gives `10` as the output.

How can I swap this problem around so that `10` is the input and `a` is the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do realize that the `10` in your example is not the ASCII code but the value of `a` as a hex digit (or rather, digit in any base greater than 10). To reverse that:

```
char c = Character.forDigit(10, 16);
```

Which you could have found by looking at the "see also" section in the API doc.

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
int i = 97;
char c = (char) i; //should yield 'a';

System.out.println( "Integer " + i + " = Character " + c );
//outputs: "Integer 10 = Character a"
```

Comment: I mean that it's completely wrong. The char/ASCII value of 'a' is 97, not 10.

Comment: @Michael, lol, im going according to the Op's Q, ill fix it ok?

Comment: No, you didn't. The OP is not wrong, he's just doing something other than converting characters to ASCII codes, and your code is not the correct reversal of that.

Answer (score -1):

```
char c = 'a';
int  i = 10;

System.out.println("Character c = [" + c + "], numeric valule = [" + (int)c + "]");
System.out.println("int i = [" + i + "], character valule = [" + (char)i + "]");
```